# Подключение слайдера через компоненту news.list

Tags: 1с

Вывел на странице слайдер (OwlCarousel2-2.3.4) через компоненту news.list (1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 18.0.2.).
Подключаю в шаблоне шапки вот так:

```
<?
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/libs/js/owl.carousel.min.js");
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/owl.carousel.init.js");
?>
```

При этом в браузере вижу, что скрипты подключаются:

```
type="text/javascript">BX.setJSList(['/bitrix/js/main/core/core.js','/bitrix/js/main/core/core_ajax.js','/bitrix/js/main/json/json2.min.js','/bitrix/js/main/core/core_ls.js','/bitrix/js/main/session.js','/bitrix/js/main/core/core_fx.js','/bitrix/js/main/core/core_window.js','/bitrix/js/main/core/core_popup.js','/bitrix/js/main/core/core_date.js','/bitrix/js/main/utils.js','/bitrix/js/pull/pull.js','/local/templates/***/libs/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js','/local/templates/***/libs/js/bootstrap.min.js','/local/templates/***/libs/js/jquery.validate.min.js','/local/templates/***/libs/js/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js','/local/templates/***/libs/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js','/local/templates/***/libs/js/phone.js','/local/templates/***/libs/js/owl.carousel.min.js','/local/templates/***/js/owl.carousel.init.js','/local/templates/***/js/nav-button.js','/local/templates/***/js/main.js']); </script>
```

Слайдер запустился, работает, но есть проблема:

При первой загрузке страницы или при ее перезагрузке в хроме с очисткой кэша (ctrl + shift + R) грузится только первая картинка слайдера в уменьшенном виде - скрин1.
[image: скрин1]

Если далее просто перегрузить страничку (не жестко), все отображается и работает корректно. Но это уже потом, а если с очисткой кэша - все повторяется.

Пробовал отключить кэш в настройках как страницы, так и компонента - не помогает.
Пробовал подключать скрипты в разных последовательностях и даже немного иным способом:

```
<?$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<script defer src="'.SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/libs/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<script defer src="'.SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/js/owl.carousel.init.js"></script>');?>
```

Ничего не меняется.

Тогда в виде эксперимента поставил брейкпоинт в виде скрипта-заглушки в самый конец страницы - скрин2:
[image: скрин2]

Так вот, при данной паузе (пока нажимаю продолжить выполнение скрипта) - страничка загружается до конца, этого времени в полсекунды хватает для того, чтобы все обработалось и отрисовалось корректно - скрин3:
[image: скрин3]

Таким образом, если кто сталкивался, подскажите почему так ведет себя компонент (или не он, а какой-нибудь механизм внутренний bitrix) и что подправить в системе, чтобы все работало правильно.

Comment: Не знаю, как OwlCarousel, но у меня была такая проблема со slick-слайдером на Битриксе. Решалась следующим образом: инициализацию слайдера надо поместить в функцию $(window).load(function() { ... }). Это позволяет дождаться полной загрузки всех изображений перед запуском слайдера. Возможно, здесь тоже такой вариант подойдёт.

Answer (score 1):

humster_spb, большое спасибо за подсказку, с ее помощью решил проблему, правда с небольшим изменением.

Если использовать вызов

```
$(window).load(function() {/*код*/});
```

то по не понятной причине валился сам jQuery с ошибкой

```
"Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function at w.fn.init.w.fn.load".
```

Ругается с своем теле начиная с этого момента:

```
s=e.indexOf(" ");return s>-1&&(r=vt(e.slice(s)),e=e.slice(0,s)),g(t)?(n=t,t=void 0):*******
```

Свежая версия jQuery не помогла, поэтому решил проблему используя стандартное событие DOM, не требующее jQuery, но делающее то же самое (вызывающее событие при загрузке объекта, **включая картинки**):

```
window.onload=function(){/**ваш код**/};
```

Все заработало как надо, спасибо.

Comment: ну да, как вариант. рад, что помогло )